# Angular 11 Material Drawer content items not binded after single click

Tags: angular, angular-material, drawer

I created a drawer container with angular 11.
If I click once on the left menu the fields of the form are not bound.
[image]
I need to double click to get the binding.
[image]

How can I get the binding of the form items on a single click?

```
<mat-drawer-container>
<mat-drawer [autoFocus]="false" [mode]="side" [opened]="true">
<ng-container *ngFor="let panel of panels; trackBy: trackByFn">
<div (click)="goToPanel(panel.id)">
<mat-icon [svgIcon]="panel.icon" ></mat-icon>
<div>{{title}}</div>
<div>{{description}}</div>
</div>
</ng-container>
</mat-drawer>

<mat-drawer-content>
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="selectedPanel">
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'accounts'"><accounts-settings></accounts-settings></ng-container>
</ng-container>
</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Comment: Does the data load only on double click, or at any pause between two clicks?

Comment: the data load also at one click. I verified it through console log but are not rendered on the DOM.

Comment: Then it might be a problem of DOM elements being loaded before the data came in, and data updating on <accounts-settings> component is done onInit, so it doesn't pick the data after changes. How does the <accounts-settings> get data to display?

Comment: Thanks. I solved inserting a refresh of the component in ngAfterContentInit

Comment: There's probably better solution, like subscribing in onInit or AfterInit or using setter/getter on @Input or adding onChanges handler for those values.